# Error while building Qt Creator Plugin

Tags: qt, qtplugin

I tried to create Qt Creator Plugin by following https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtcreator-extending/first-plugin.html , but I failed to build with a link error

> ld: library not found for -lCore_debug
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> make: *** [../qt5/build_creator/bin/Qt Creator.app/Contents/PlugIns/libMyPlugin_debug.dylib] Error 1
>
> 21:58:13: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
>
> Error while building/deploying project myplugin (kit: Qt 5.5.0 (clang_64))
>
> When executing step "Make"

Please anybody let me know what's wrong with me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting _debug keyword in {my plugin project}/qtcreatorplugin/qtcreator.pri

I think it is a bug because we don't need to *_debug library to debug own plugin. But I am not sure my solution don't happen any other problems.

Anyway, I was able to build and run on debug mode.